# MeteorJS (MongoDB) with Spark

Tags: mongodb, meteor, apache-spark

I am using MeteorJS framework for one of my project .
I have build a basic webApp once before using MeteorJS and it works perfectly fine when its just Client, Server and MongoDB.

In this project, I want the monogDB (which comes in build with MeteorJS) to populate data from Apache Spark.

Basically, Apache Spark will process some data and inject it into mongoDB
Is this doable ?
Please can you point me to the right tutorial for this 
How complex is this to implement ?
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is very possible and quite easy. That said it won't be via MeteorJS, it would be part of the Apache Spark job and would be configured there.

Using the [MongoDB Spark Connector](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/) taking data from a DataFrame or an RDD and saving it to MongoDB is easy.

First you would configure how and where the data is written:

```
// Configure where to save the data
val writeConfig = WriteConfig(Map("uri" -> "mongodb://localhost/databaseName.collectionName"))
```

With RDD's you should convert them into Documents via a map function eg:

```
val documentRDD = rdd.map(data => Document) // map the RDD into documents
MongoSpark.save(documentRDD, writeConfig)
```

If you are using DataFrames it's much easier as you can just provide a DataFrameWriter and writeConfig:

```
MongoSpark.save(dataFrame.write, writeConfig)
```

There is more information in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/) or there are examples in the [github repo](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/tree/master/examples/src/test).

Comment: Thanks will give it a try. 
Why did you say it wont be via MeteorJS ?
I mean MeteorJS will also install mongo as a part of its package. So all I will need to do is use the MongoDB Spark Connector to inject data from Spark
 --> Mongo
And then when mongo is updated with new data , the meteor server will fetch the updated data and push it to its respective clients via web socket , right ?
Please correct me if I'm wrong here

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. I mentioned it won't be via MeteorJS as the meteor app is orthogonal to core issue: how do you get data from Spark into MongoDB.

Comment: I think the point here is that you need to setup your own instance of MongoDB: Spark will save to it, and you need to use MONGO_URL to point Meteor to it. That is, do not use the built in Mongo instance... Anyway if you're using Spark, that assumes you have a fair amount of data to process, and a single MongoDB instance probably won't be suitable. If you don't have that much data, maybe you're trying to kill a fly with a hammer and you don't need Spark.)

Comment: Thank you will give it a try